# Unreal situation in the past

Tags: past-tense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Would have had to have been” vs “would have had to be” for past event conditions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50231/would-have-had-to-have-been-vs-would-have-had-to-be-for-past-event-condition)

What's the difference in meaning between these phrases?

> would've had to jump
>   would've had to have jumped

As far as I understand, they both describe an unreal situation in the past, but I can't figure out the difference.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, I agree, it is a duplicate. What should I do with my question?

Comment: @Gebb: You don't have to do anything. The question will remain open unless others agree that it should be closed. It's a good question, but it's best if answers to it are all given in the same place.

Comment: @Gebb You can vote to close it too. The OPs are always able to vote to close their own questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first describes an unreal situation in the past.

> I would have had to jump to have made it across the chasm.

The second describes an unreal situation in the past, that is also prior to some other (unreal) situation in the past.

> I would have had to have jumped across the chasm in order to have seen the hidden valley.

Comment: Your both examples describe a situation and a subsequent situation. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's actually "a situation and a subsequent situation" prior to the present. That is, the subsequent situation is not the present.  So, the second statement implies a reference to a third interim point of time between the *past* of the first statement and the present.